# Webclient (fom Mozilla) under Linux

Tags: linux, firefox, java, webclient

I could not start Webclient under Linux ( due to factory class for GTK could not be found)

Does anybody know the solution of this problem?

Comment: Please provide more information.

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a SuperUser.com question .
My wild guess is that there is some version incompatibility(thus wrong path etc.).
You should check that GTK is properly installed, but first  I would download another build of Firefox and try that first.